# ¿Por que tengo un loop en mi ciclo for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un método `ActionResult` el cual tiene un ciclo `for` donde recorro todas las `cookies` para eliminarlas al hacer logout. El problema es que cuando llamo al método desde mi vista (Esto a través de un `form`) entro al metodo pero nunca termino de salir del ciclo `for` esoy en un loop y no se por que. El contador al momento de entrar me indica que existen x `cookies` pero al momento de ir recorriendolas me va sumando una mas al contador del `for` y no temrino nunca saliendo.

Mi código:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("account/exit")]
public RedirectResult LogOff()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(HttpContext.Request.Cookies[i].Name);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        cookie.Value = string.Empty;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    Session.Abandon();

    return Redirect("miurl");
}
```

Desde mi vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
    }
```

Comment: no será por que haces esto Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);? cada vez que entra al ciclo le vas sumando uno haciéndolo infinito

Comment: Si pense que podria ser otra cosa, pero entonces como elimino las cookies? lo que hice para solucionar el tema por el momento fue colocarle en el for el valor toal de las cookies en numero.

Comment: Haz un count antes de for, algo así: int noCookies =Request.Cookies.Count y ya después el for for (int i = 0; i < noCookies; i++) supongo así no deberás tener problemas

Answer (score 2):

Esto no lo he probado, pero puedes tratar de tomar los nombres de las cookies antes de eliminarlas:

```
var cookieNames = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.ToList();
```

Luego limpiar la colección de cookies:

```
Response.Cookies.Clear();
Request.Cookies.Clear(); // En caso de...
```

Y finalmente agregar las cookies:

```
foreach (var cookieName in cookieNames) {
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie { 
        Name = cookieName,
        Value = string.Empty,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
    });
}
```

Tu método quedaría así:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("account/exit")]
public RedirectResult LogOff()
{
    // Obtenemos los nombres. 
    var cookieNames = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.ToList();

    // Limpiamos las listas.
    Response.Cookies.Clear();
    Request.Cookies.Clear(); // En caso de...

    // Re-agregamos las cookies con los nuevos valores.
    foreach (var cookieName in cookieNames)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie { 
            Name = cookieName,
            Value = string.Empty,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
        });
    }

    // Terminamos.
    Session.Abandon();
    return Redirect("miurl");
}
```

Eso debería servir (Basado en [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922762/how-do-i-convert-the-cookies-collection-to-a-generic-list-easily) link), aunque preferirias editar las cookies directamente en `Response.Cookies`:

```
foreach (var cookieName in Response.Cookies.AllKeys) 
{
    Response.Cookies[cookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies[cookieName].Value = string.Empty;
}
```

Con eso otro debería bastar para ajustar la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: Pero las cookies en si no se eliminan solo las deja vacia, ya que si en el navegador reviso las cookies aun aparecen sus nombres pero sin valores. ¿Esto estaria bien? ¿Existe la forma de eliminarlas por completo?

Comment: Al hacer `Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);` haces que el navegador elimine las cookies automaticamente al terminar todo el trabajo.

Comment: Es que utilizo esa forma, pero no se eliminan del navegador, simplemente las deja vacía. Como mencione en el comentario anterior, si ingreso a revisar las cookies del navegador aun siguen ahí, pero vacias.

Comment: ¿Probaste a cerrar y abrir el navegador? Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, realmente no es culpa de tu aplicación, el navegador puede mantener las cookies aún luego de estar expiradas.

Comment: Vale la pena leer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx